# What exactly does autocommit do in a DB GUI tool?

Tags: sql-server

I am using DBVisualizer for macOS. I see an option called auto commit. I have it turned off. So when I close the software it asks whether to commit or rollback. But I have performed only `SELECT` queries. So why does a commit require in this case unless it is changing something in the table? Most of the time I want read-only mode, so I disabled the auto-commit feature. Can someone explain why I need a commit in this case. It is MS-SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the select statement started a transaction, which should be terminated appropriately by either committing or rolling back. If no actual changes were made to any table, then the choice is logically irrelevant. Refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql

Though the choice of termination is irrelevant, the application is not sufficiently intelligent to know that no changes were made; it only knows that there is an open transaction. Hence, the prompt.